# Command Line: z is installed but can't find the command

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, zsh, iterm2

I recently installed iTerm2 and ZSH (with oh-my-zsh) after some months of very light usage of the stock Terminal on Mac OS.

I heard of a tool called "z" and installed it via brew with `brew install z`. I used it for one night with no problems. Later on it stopped working, saying `zsh: command not found: z`. I tried installing it again, and was met with `Warning: z-1.8 already installed`.

How does this make sense? It's installed but the command is not found? How could I go about restoring this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: `brew list -f z` to see all files installed for the `z` formula.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do I do with the result of this command? How is this useful for me?

Comment: In fact, if you run the command I gave you, you'll see that no such command as `z` is installed. You'll have `/usr/local/Cellar/z/1.9/etc/profile.d/z.sh` (or 1.8 in your case; you appear to have outdated formula definitions). You should follow the caveats sections of `brew info z`, which says ``For Bash or Zsh, put something like this in your $HOME/.bashrc or $HOME/.zshrc: . `brew --prefix`/etc/profile.d/z.sh``.

Comment: Oh, by the way you shouldn't use that obsolete syntax. Replace that `brew --prefix` with `/usr/local`, or at least wrap it in `$()` instead.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! If you'd like to post this as an actual answer instead of a comment, I will certainly upvote and accept as the correct answer.

Comment: Sure, will try to expand into a potentially useful answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One can inspect the list of files installed by a Homebrew formula via `brew list -f <formula_name>`. In this case, the output should like

```
> brew list -f z
/usr/local/Cellar/z/1.9/etc/profile.d/z.sh
/usr/local/Cellar/z/1.9/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
/usr/local/Cellar/z/1.9/README
/usr/local/Cellar/z/1.9/share/man/man1/z.1
```

Note that in this case there's no command (and not even `bin`), just a `z.sh`. This makes sense because `z` is a shell tool, and have to be sourced into the shell as functions to get and set the shell environment; running as an external command simply doesn't offer deep enough integration. Therefore, you have to source `z.sh` into your shell, probably in `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, or `.zshrc`.

Usually, Homebrew formulae that require post-installation interactions in order to be usable will have instructions listed in caveats, which will be shown post-install, or manually retrieved via `brew info <formula_name>`. In this case,

```
> brew info z
<irrelevant info omitted>
==> Caveats
For Bash or Zsh, put something like this in your $HOME/.bashrc or $HOME/.zshrc:
  . `brew --prefix`/etc/profile.d/z.sh
```

Of course you should take that advise with a grain of salt, and use more modern and human-readable shell syntax:

```
source "$(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/z.sh"
```

Or

```
source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/z.sh
```

if you know your Homebrew installation is in `/usr/local`.

Comment: P.S. By "more modern and human-readable shell syntax" I'm comparing to the POSIX shell... Unfortunate folks writing shell-agnostic shell tools are stuck to POSIX, but the rest of us who know we're using something better don't have to conform to that.

Answer (score 4):

in Mac osx with iterm2 with zsh just put:

First:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

and add this line (or just add z)

```
plugins=(
    git
    z
)
```

exit with

```
:x!
```

that's it.

Comment: Put it *where*?  Type it?  When?  Every time you login?  What does it do?    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Brew installs things in `/usr/local/bin` rather than `/usr/bin` to avoid needing root priveleges. Often [this needs adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025980/how-to-add-usr-local-bin-in-path-on-mac) to your `$PATH` (the default directories to look for applications and scripts) - especially if you've changed shells. Once added you should have access to all your Brew-installed commands again.

Comment: Looks like it's already added. When I echo my $PATH, I get `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin`, it seems like in there.